# Perl function similar to wc in grep -c?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I am trying to write a script that goes through an entire folder of text files, matching a string pattern. What I want is the count of patterns matched in each file. In unix it could be done by `grep -c <pattern> *`. where the `-c` option returns you the count. Is there any way to get that count using perl regex?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $grep_count = grep (/PATTERN/, @array);
```

Or for a file:

```
perl -we "print scalar grep /PATTERN/, <>;" file.txt
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but just write it, when you open each file, use `while` to go through each of its lines, and use =~ against each line (with your pattern), if matched, then add 1 to your counter.